# How to fix : " Error: data and hash arguments required "

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, bcrypt

I'm trying login with a user that I have registered in my form but I have this error:

> Error: data and hash arguments required

The user is registered in my database with a Username, Fullname and the hashed password thanks to bcrypt.

```
const pool = require("./pool");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

function User() {}

User.prototype = {
  find: function(user = null, callback) {

  if (user) {
      var field = Number.isInteger(user) ? "id" : "username";
    }
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE ${"" + field + ""} = ?`;
    pool.query(sql, user, function(err, result) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      callback(result);
    });
  },

  create: function(body, callback) {
    let pwd = body.password;
    body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(pwd, 10);

    var bind = [body.username, body.fullname, body.password];
    console.log(bind);

    let sql =
      "INSERT INTO users(username, fullname, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    pool.query(sql, bind, function(err, lastId) {
      if (err) throw err;
      callback(lastId);
    });
  },

  login: function(username, password, callback) {
    this.find(username, function(user) {
      if (user) {
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
          callback(user);
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  }
};

module.exports = User;
```

Once i press my login button in my form this is the error I'm getting

```
  throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
  ^
```

```
    at Object.compareSync (/Users/me/happy/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:167:15)
    at /Users/me/happy/core/user.js:46:20
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/me/happy/core/user.js:16:7)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/me/happy/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at Query._callback (/Users/me/happy/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:491:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/me/happy/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/Users/me/happy/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/Users/me/happy/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/me/happy/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/Users/me/happy/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are passing valid values in both arguments. userpassword and dbpassword should not be undefined or null

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate a salt synchronously, updating this line

```
body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(pwd, 10);
```

for

```
body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(pwd, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));
```

Comment: Doesn't work :/ i think something is missing in my compareSync parameters

Answer (score 0):

Please check `password` and `user.password` is not equal to undefined. Because the same function is working fine for me. 
If you are still facing the same issue then please try `bcrypt.compare`. `bcrypt.compare` takes 3 parameters passwordToCheck, passwordHash and a callback.

```
login: function(username, password, callback) {
    this.find(username, function(user) {
        if (user) {
            bcrypt.compare(password,  user.password, function(err, match) {
                if (err) throw new Error(err);
                else if (match == false) {
                    return res.json({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'Wrong Password'
                    })
                } else {
                    callback(user);
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```